# Curved Screen for Monitor in Blender?

Tags: unity, blender

I'm trying do get a curved plane for an oldschool monitor but have still no clue how to achive this, even not after hours of searching with Google.

This is what I currently have and I need to curve this plane to look like the curved screen of an tube monitor.

Any ideas how I can achieve this?
Thank you in advance! :)

[image]

Comment: You should probably ask this on the blender SE

Comment: I flagged this post, it doesn't belong here.

Comment: Should be asked on https://blender.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I can't seem to find a consensus on meta that Blender questions are off-topic here, hence I'm voting to leave the question open. However, as mentioned above, you will get better answers on Blender.SE.

Comment: Blender questions are not off-topic here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick tutorial I made about making a curved surface. Maybe play around with the proportional falloff type: https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cbi3oHlUDh

Comment: Perfect! That is exactly what I was searching for. Thank you very much :)